# No value returned on img tag

Tags: javascript

I'm making a basic card game and I need to return the value of the clicked card but I'm getting an undefined error message.

```
function flipCard(){
    var g = document.getElementById("playingCard").value;
    alert(g);
}

<body>
    <img src="card.png" id="playingCard" value="20" onclick="flipCard()"/>
</body>
```

Comment: I doubt there is just one playing card, so I wonder if they all have the same id.  Pass the `this` param to flipCard and *that* is the img that was clicked, no need to mess around with getElementById.

Comment: Please note that 'value' is not a supported attribute for the img tag. For custom attribute use 'data-value'.

Comment: @James correct there are more cards but I was just trying to get one to work and return the results I am looking for. I will try that d3L. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

`img` tag does not have default property of `value`. You can try `getAttribute` function.

```
function flipCard(){
    var g = document.getElementById("playingCard").getAttribute('value');
    alert(g);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: OMG it works!! Thank you sooo much. I researched and tried 100 different options for 2 hours last night. The simplest solutions drive me nuts.

Comment: ok now that Ive added to other cards the only value that returns is from the first card in the list. in location 0. i added a "value="" to empty out the variable within function before it gets attribute